# How can I disable the sharing of one mouse between several X ServerLayouts?

Tags: xorg, mouse, multiseat

I run a two-seat setup of Ubuntu 11.10. It is achieved via two ServerLayout sections inside of xorg.conf. The movements of the mouse belonging to seat 1 should not be visible on seat 2, but they are. But no matter which xorg.conf configuration I tried (and I researched and experimented relentlessly for six hours now), I cannot prevent this.

I placed my hopes into the "void" input driver. At various places in the internet it is suggested that /dev/input/mice should be disabled, and one specific mouse device node used instead. I did the following, but no success:

```
Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier "dummy"
    Driver     "void"
    Option     "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option     "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
        Identifier  "Mouse0"
        Driver      "mouse"
        Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mouse0"
EndSection
```

Even if I add **only** InputDevice "dummy" into a ServerLayout section (instead of Mouse0), the mouse is still functional. I even added Option "CorePointer" to the dummy InputDevice, but still the mouse works.

I've noticed a similar thing with the keyboard. If the driver "kbd" is used, the input seems to be shared across several X ServerLayouts. If I use "evdev" instead, it only is applied to the current ServerLayout.

I also don't understand the concept of a "CorePointer" clearly. Is it a mouse pointer that is shared across all server instances?

I feel I've exhausted all available forum threads and man pages on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were additional X configuration files in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d which interfered with the configuration in xorg.conf. I removed these files and commented out the interfering parts. It now works.